# Solve recurrences in Big-Theta notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

Can someone help me with (b) and (c). I really don't know how to solve it, whether using substitution or recurrence tree method. Master theorem doesn't seem to work here either. Thanks.[image: PROBLEM]

Comment: Off-topic for SO, but part (b) can be handled by Akra--Bazzi (it's linear). If you need a substitution proof, replace O(1) with c1 and Theta(n) with c2 n where c1 and c2 are unspecified constants and turn the crank. Part (c) does not have a unique solution with respect to big-Theta notation, since the answer is different when a = b = n/2 versus a = b = n/4. If I were an algorithms TA again I'd write actual numbers everywhere instead of sneaking in another two layers of quantifiers that create confusion but don't really change the problem.